# How can I absorb Toriel's SOUL?

Tags: undertale

In my first playthrough of Undertale, after killing Toriel, instead of her SOUL cracking and shattering, it was merged with mine. It happened only on my first playthrough (neutral).

Here's what I know for sure:

- I got hit by flowey. I didn't evade his "friendliness pallets".
- I killed the dummy.
- I took all the candies I could from the jar (tipping it over)
- I bought one of the cheaper kind of spider products.
- I did not take the Toy Knife, I fought Toriel with my stick.
- I never fled from a battle.
- I "killed" Napstablook.
- I picked Cinnamon when asked.
- I never called Toriel back during my stay at the RUINs.
- I tried to talk to Toriel once, spare her once, then proceeded to attack her for the rest of the battle.
- I didn't reach 2HP (her attacks didn't evade me)
- I didn't die at any point in the RUINs.

What I don't remember for sure:

- Did I get the pie? I didn't go to sleep. But I don't remember if I had gotten it nevertheless.
- If I had gotten the pie, did I eat it during her battle?
- Exactly which monsters I've killed during my stay at the RUINS.

---

I don't have a savefile of the game, I only discovered that it was abnormal after I've done a genocide run and decided to wipe the game files for a true pacifist run.

I've made neutral, pacifist, genocide, pacifist runs, in that order. I obviously didn't see it in the pacifist, and I attributed her SOUL shattering in the genocide run to my cruelty (I hit her so hard, her SOUL couldn't recover).

Have anyone experienced this? Do you know what can possibly be done to attempt and reproduce this? I'll answer any clarification requests in the comments, this issue is driving me crazy!

Comment: Do you remember anything about the scene itself ? Did you see the two hearts merging together or something ? Because I really can't remember any situation involving Toriel's soul merging with anything.

Comment: Her soul moved towards mine, there was a fancy WHOOOSH sound effect too. Everything else seemed pretty much like what I've seen in YouTube playthroughs. I stand in front of the door alone, and flowey greets me on the edge of the corridor.

Comment: That's really an interesting question. I'm gonna reset my save and try your conditions to see if I can achieve such a thing.
Do you remember if it had any influence on the rest of the game ?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't thinking of later scenes (like when [spoiler] Asriel/Flowey absorb the souls)? This shouldn't happen, and doesn't make any sense story-wise, unless you've stumbled across some incredibly rare easter egg.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. :/

Comment: @sumelic I'm not making this up. Although given the responses I'm starting to doubt my memory. I bought and downloaded it on Jan 28th on Steam.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha What you're stating here is not possible. People have decompiled the game and there is no code in it that could make this kind of a scene happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A private email discussion with Toby Fox reveals that I was in fact misremembering or imagining, and that Toriel's SOUL always shatters when she's killed.

The exact mail wording as follows:

> You did imagine it, the soul always shatters. You misremembered it. Or had deja vu that you thought was real.

Comment: You can actually see this phenomenon firsthand by watching Let's Play Undertale videos on YouTube; for example, near the end of Joseph Anderson's first playthrough he mentioned remembering absorbing Toriel's soul, but if you go back and rewatch the segment wherein he fought Toriel, no such absorption occurred.

Comment: **Deja Vu plays in the background**

Answer (score 3):

This is quite unusual but yes, i have experienced it on my first play through. What happened was i (accidently..) killed Toriel... This might have been different for you because i think this is a glitch. For me, Toriel's heart "refused" and fused with mine. This must have been [spoiler alert] a glitch from:

> Asriel's fight where the soul "refuses".

The merging part was a glitch from:

> Omega Flowey's boss fight when he absorbs the soul.

Other stuff happened to me afterwards like:

1. Gaster door opened
2. Undyne fight: True heroine and neutral/pacifist Undyne fight music playing at the same time
3. Gave me the pacifist after genocide ending and not Omega Flowey.(The one where you go pacifist but when you wake up you have a red glimmer in your eye.. and Chara's face...)

Mine had allot more issues than yours did... I reset but, instead of Toriel saying: You look like you have seen a ghost my child (something like that anyway), she went along like it was the first time. Even in judgement hall.. No one remembered the last reset.. So that went in deep but yeah it's happened to me..

Comment: You had a "FUN" value of 66, which causes the Gaster door to spawn (The sprite's name is "MysteryMan", however).

Answer (score -3):

This, after what the first answer said, is likely a fun value easter egg. Fun values, when (somehow) set to a certain value, caused all sorts of insane stuff to occur, such as Gaster's room. This is probably the reason why this was caused.

Answer (score -3):

Literally, the first ever time I saw the Toriel fight was on my friend's laptop. This was literally my first encounter with Undertake, so I wasn't spoiled to anything. He was doing a neutral run, I believe, or he was just killing the boss monsters. And **when he killed Toriel, her soul got absorbed into his**.